# Git flow guideline for CI and CD

Tags: git, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, git-flow

I would like to Integrate CI and CD  with VSTS.
I was going through the different link but getting confused, what process to follow. Attached git flow image[image]

In this flow .

1. The integration release will happen from develop branch?
2. UAT release will happened from which branch? is it from master?
3. Production Release should happened from master?
4. If i need to integrate sonar or any static analysis tool which branch i need to integrate.

Please suggest me what should be the best git flow i can use in this case. I'm also attaching our current git flow.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions of the main branches as below:

- `develop` branch is for all developers to manage their works.
- `master` branch is the main branch to manage the production versions.
- `release` branches are the branches for preparing a new release (if UAT is necessary for your situation).

For the git flow with the branching model which you attached as below:

- All the developers works on `develop` branch, and they can develop new features on theirs own feature branches. After finishing the work on feature branches, they should merge into `develop` branch.
- If UAT is necessary for your git flow, you should create release branches for each new releases. Such as when you prepare to release the version for `1.0`, you can create a release branch `release-1.0` for UAT. And when it's ready, merge the release branch `release-1.0` into `master` branch for the new  production version.
- For a release, if it's unnecessary to do UAT, then merge `develop` into `master` branch for a new release directly.

More details about the git flow explanation, you can refer the post [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

So for your questions:

1. The CI build should be based on your requirements. And it's also ok to set CI buils both for `develop` branch and `master` branch.
2. UAT happens on release branches. When it's passed, then merge the release branches into `master` branch.
3. Yes, production release happens on `master` branch.
4. The analysis should be excuted in your CI build (in the same branch(es) triggered by CI build(s)).

Comment: Thanks you so much for detailed explanation. So develop branch create from master and feature branch create from develop. Just one doubt. Suppose i had a two feature branch and i merged both the features for uat to develop branch. And team is asking after merge to develop to include a new change. But I delete both the features branch. So at this time i need to include the new request after creating release branch in release? Or can i create again a feature branch from develop?

Comment: develop is a long-living branch, it should merge into master (if there has no uat), and release branches should create from develop branch. And yes, feature branches create from develop branch.

Comment: If you already merge two feature branches into develop branch, but want to create a new release branch which exclude the changes from the two feature branches, then there are multiple options you can follow: option1, create feature branches to include the changes and reset develop branch, then create a release branch from develop; option2, create a release from previous commit (which not contains the feature changes) on develop branch by `git checkout -b release-x.x commit`.